# Hide the icon of main window when navigate to another window

Tags: c#, wpf, icons, hide

In my Wpf application, I've four windows. For every window, I've written following code so it could minimize to system tray. But problem is when navigate from one window to another, first window's icon still appears in system tray. I just want to hide that icon when navigate to another window? Please suggest the ways to proceed?

My Main window code is-

```
public partial class MonthView : MetroWindow
{

    public DateTime SelectedDate { get; set; }
    private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenu1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem2;

    public MonthView()
    {

            InitializeComponent();
            calMain.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
            Globals._globalController = new AppController();
            Globals._globalController.appTaskManager.setupLocal();
            Globals._globalController.setMonthViewWindow(this);

            Globals.ni = new NotifyIcon();
            this.contextMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
            this.menuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
            this.menuItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
            Globals.ni.Icon = TimeSheet.Properties.Resources.MonthViewIcon;
            Globals.ni.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni.Click +=
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                this.Show();
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

            };

            this.contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] { this.menuItem1 });

            this.contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] { this.menuItem2 });

            this.menuItem1.Text = "Start";
            this.menuItem2.Text = "Exit";
            Globals.ni.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu1;
    }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Globals.ni.BalloonTipTitle = "MonthView";
            Globals.ni.BalloonTipText = "This is main window";
            Globals.ni.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            base.OnStateChanged(e);
        }
    }

    public void calItemSelectedDate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime d;
        if (sender is DateTime)
        {
            d = (DateTime)sender;
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime.TryParse(sender.ToString(), out d);
        }

        SelectedDate = d;

        ShowActivity(d);
     }

    public void ShowActivity(DateTime date)
    {
        DayView Activity = new DayView(date);
        Activity.Show();
        this.Hide();

    }

    private void SetButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SettingsView set = new SettingsView();
        set.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }

 }
```

Comment: Why are you using `System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu`s and `System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem`s if this is a WPF project? Otherwise, why have you added the WPF tag if this is not a WPF project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have the windows share one NotifyIcon? You can switch the NotifyIcon's icon when you switch views. You already have a global "singleton" holding onto it.

Creating a new icon for each screen means there are four icons there, and since you walk over the static reference, you no longer have access to the NotifyIcon.

Comment: But this brings up a question. If you're only going to ever allow one view, why aren't you simply making the views in a control that sits on the main window.

Answer (score 0):

WPF `Window`s have a `ShowInTaskbar` property. Set this to `false`.

You may also be interested in this post:

[C# WPF - Application Icon + ShowInTaskbar = False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358677/c-sharp-wpf-application-icon-showintaskbar-false)